# Issue with Decimals, Commas and Client-Side Validation

Tags: javascript, jquery, validation, asp.net-mvc-4

I'm trying to achieve client-side validation for a `nullable<decimal>` whose decimal separator can be a comma (e.g.: 123,45).

In my View:

```
...

<div class="editor-label">
    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Turnover)
</div>
<div class="editor-field">
    @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Turnover)
    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Turnover)
</div>

...

@section Scripts {

   @Styles.Render("~/Content/themes/base/css")
   @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jquery")
   @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryui")
   @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryval")
   @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jQueryFixes")
   ...scripts for this view...
}
```

My jQueryFixes overrides `jquery.validate.js` file for the `range()` and `number()`:

```
$.validator.methods.range = function (value, element, param) {
    var globalizedValue = value.replace(",", ".");
    return this.optional(element) || (globalizedValue >= param[0] && globalizedValue <= param[1]);
}

$.validator.methods.number = function (value, element) {
    return this.optional(element) || /^-?(?:\d+|\d{1,3}(?:[\s\.,]\d{3})+)(?:[\.,]\d+)?$/.test(value);
}
```

...as suggested in many posts/questions regarding this issue (e.g.: [here](http://rebuildall.umbraworks.net/2011/03/02/jQuery_validate_and_the_comma_decimal_separator) or [here](http://www.mfranc.com/uncategorized/jquery-valdiator-modyfing-decimal-separator/)).

**Strangely enough:**

When I try to submit a value such as 123,45, and even though I've debugged the script with Firebug and seen that my overrode functions are being called and returning true, I'm not being able to submit the form. Instead, my EditorFor for the decimal value is being focused for whatever reason and I can't seem to find out why.

(I believe that my server-side validation - using a custom binder, etc. - is working fine and that **is not the issue here**: I would like some help on how to get the form to submit or why is the input field getting focused even though it looks valid.)

**EDIT 1:**

Additional info. In my BundlesConfig.cs:

```
bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/jquery").Include(
                    "~/Scripts/jquery-{version}.js"));
...
bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/jqueryui").Include(
                    "~/Scripts/jquery-ui-{version}.js"));
bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/jqueryval").Include(
                    "~/Scripts/jquery.unobtrusive*",
                    "~/Scripts/jquery.validate*"));
bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/jQueryFixes").Include(
                    "~/Scripts/jQueryFixes.js")); 
...
```

**EDIT 2:**

After @LeftyX suggestion, I tried using the Globalize script (after removing my jQueryFixes.js):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    ...

    $( document ).ready(function() {
        Globalize.culture("en-US", "pt-PT");
    });

    $.validator.methods.number = function (value, element) {
        return this.optional(element) || jQuery.isNumeric(Globalize.parseFloat(value));
    }

    //Fix the range to use globalized methods
    jQuery.extend(jQuery.validator.methods, {
        range: function (value, element, param) {
            var val = Globalize.parseFloat(value);
            return this.optional(element) || (val >= param[0] && val <= param[1]);
        }
    });

   ...
</script>
```

...but I still face the same issue: the `validator.methods.number` is returning true but the form isn't submitted and the input field gets focused instead.

If I inspect the input element while I submit, I can see that it quickly goes from `class="valid"` to `class='input-validation-error'` and then back to `valid`. Very strange.

**CONCLUSION:**

@LeftyX gave a very good and complete solution for whoever finds the same issues.

I already had a custom model binder for the nullable decimals, but the globalization script and including the culture in the Model/ViewModel sure comes in handy.

Another reason for my problem could be the fact that I was (accidentally) including some scripts twice.

**UPDATE (Jul/2015):**

[globalize.js](https://github.com/jquery/globalize) is a bit different now. Ref. to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20263762/issue-with-decimals-commas-and-client-side-validation/31263906#31263906) and [the documentation](https://github.com/jquery/globalize) for the updated steps.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I've struggled quite a bit with this.

The best approach for me is to define a custom binder for decimals:

```
public class DecimalModelBinder : IModelBinder
{
    public object BindModel(ControllerContext controllerContext,
        ModelBindingContext bindingContext)
    {
        ValueProviderResult valueResult = bindingContext.ValueProvider
            .GetValue(bindingContext.ModelName);
        ModelState modelState = new ModelState { Value = valueResult };
        object actualValue = null;
        try
        {
            //Check if this is a nullable decimal and a null or empty string has been passed
            var isNullableAndNull = (bindingContext.ModelMetadata.IsNullableValueType &&
                                     string.IsNullOrEmpty(valueResult.AttemptedValue));

            //If not nullable and null then we should try and parse the decimal
            if (!isNullableAndNull)
            {
                actualValue = Convert.ToDecimal(valueResult.AttemptedValue, CultureInfo.CurrentCulture);
            }
        }
        catch (FormatException e)
        {
            modelState.Errors.Add(e);
        }

        bindingContext.ModelState.Add(bindingContext.ModelName, modelState);
        return actualValue;
    }
}
```

and bind it in the `Application_Start` in `Global.asax`:

```
ModelBinders.Binders.Add(typeof(decimal), new DecimalModelBinder());
ModelBinders.Binders.Add(typeof(decimal?), new DecimalModelBinder());
```

I also use the globalize script (with cultures) which can be found [here](https://github.com/jquery/globalize) or downloaded from nuget [here](http://www.nuget.org/packages/jquery-globalize/).

Your bundle should look something like this:

```
bundles.Add(ScriptBundle("~/bundles/jquery").Include(
    "~/Scripts/jquery-{version}.js",
    "~/Scripts/globalize.js",
    "~/Scripts/cultures/globalize.culture.en-GB.js",
    "~/Scripts/cultures/globalize.culture.it-IT.js"
    ));
```

**Of course you can add more culures if you want to support different localizations.**

Now, when your DOM is ready (javascript) you can define your culture:

```
Globalize.culture('en-GB');

$.validator.methods.number = function (value, element) {
    return this.optional(element) || jQuery.isNumeric(Globalize.parseFloat(value));
}

//Fix the range to use globalized methods
jQuery.extend(jQuery.validator.methods, {
    range: function (value, element, param) {
    var val = Globalize.parseFloat(value);
    return this.optional(element) || (val >= param[0] && val <= param[1]);
    }
});

$.validator.methods.date = function (value, element) {
    return (this.optional(element) || Globalize.parseDate(value));
}
```

and customize your validations (I've added the date as well).  You've done that in your `jQueryFixes`.

You can find a working example [here](https://skydrive.live.com/redir?resid=669ADF1AF64DF389!242) (MvcAppForDecimals) where you can change languages 
using a toolbar and cookies so that the culture can change on the server as well.

In the example I read the cookie in `Application_BeginRequest` or use the default culture define in the web.config:

```
<globalization enableClientBasedCulture="true" uiCulture="en-GB" culture="en-GB" />
```

I've also defined a ActionFilter (LanguageFilterAttribute) which injects the current culture in a base viewmodel so the client uses the current set on the server side.

An extended explanation can be found [here](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/GlobalizationInternationalizationAndLocalizationInASPNETMVC3JavaScriptAndJQueryPart1.aspx).

Some more info about the globalize script and culture settings [here](https://github.com/jquery/globalize#defining-culture-information).

Comment: Hey. Very nice&complete answer, thanks. 

I already had my DecimalModelBinder but that isn't the issue here as I'm struggling with client-side validation (i.e. the form isn't even submitted to the server so that the ModelBinder can do its work).

I've added the Globalize script, though, and I'm still facing the same issue: it's as if the validation is accepting the value but something else is preventing this from being submitted.

Comment: Thanks. The problem is the server and the client are using different cultures, probably. Globalize script and the DecimalModelBinder allow you to avoid checking commas or dots as decimals but you have to set the culture you want to use. You can have a look at my sample code.

Comment: Now that was a lot of work for something so simple! Your working example was a big help too. Thanks & upvote.

Answer (score 1):

Just a small update regarding [globalize.js](https://github.com/jquery/globalize). Things are a bit different (and confusing) now:

Include the scripts as follows:

```
<!--
First, we load Globalize's dependencies (`cldrjs` and its supplemental
module).
-->
<script type="text/javascript" src="~/Scripts/cldr.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="~/Scripts/cldr/event.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="~/Scripts/cldr/supplemental.js"></script>

<!--
Next, we load Globalize and its modules.
-->
<script type="text/javascript" src="~/Scripts/globalize.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="~/Scripts/globalize/number.js"></script>
```

Now we need to [load the I18n content onto Globalize](https://github.com/jquery/globalize/blob/master/doc/cldr.md):

```
<script type='text/javascript'>

    // At this point, we have Globalize loaded. But, before we can use it, we
    // need to feed it on the appropriate I18n content (Unicode CLDR). In order
    // to do so, we use `Globalize.load()` and pass the content.

    $.when($.getJSON('/Scripts/cldr/supplemental/likelySubtags.json'),
               $.getJSON('/Scripts/cldr/main/en-GB/numbers.json'),
               ...other locales...
               $.getJSON('/Scripts/cldr/supplemental/numberingSystems.json'))
        .done(function (result1, result2, result3, result4) {
            Globalize.load(result1[0]); //contains data of first executed request
            ...load the other ones...
            Globalize.load(result3[0]); //contains data of third executed request
            Globalize.load(result4[0]); //contains data of fourth executed request

            var glob = Globalize([YOUR-LOCALE]); // e.g. en-UK, pt-PT, pt-BR, es-ES, etc.

            $.validator.methods.number = function (value, element) {
                var number = glob.parseNumber(value);
                return this.optional(element) || jQuery.isNumeric(number);
            }

            //Fix the range to use globalized methods
            jQuery.extend(jQuery.validator.methods, {
                range: function (value, element, param) {
                    var val = glob.formatNumber(value);
                    return this.optional(element) || (val >= param[0] && val <= param[1]);
                }

        });
    });

</script>
```

The I18n content is available as JSON [here](https://github.com/unicode-cldr/).

If you get 404 on your `getJSON()`, remember to add:

```
<system.webServer>

    (...)

    <staticContent>
      <mimeMap fileExtension=".json" mimeType="application/json" />
    </staticContent>

</system.webServer>
```

in your Web.config (ASP .NET MVC application).

Comment: There is problem with *//Fix the range to use globalized methods*. After executing this code, client validation does not work. Browser automatically submit form to the server without client validation. I am not sure why.